# PowerShell Write-EventLog CmdLet works manually, not in script

Tags: powershell, event-log, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a PowerShell script to disable and move users with in AD.  this part works great.  However I would like to log each event in the event log. The cmdlet `Write-EventLog` works fine when typed manually.

```
Write-EventLog –LogName ManageAD –Source “ManageUsers Script” –EntryType Information –EventID 1 –Message “This is a test message"
```

However, when I add the cmdlet to the script it errors.

```
Write-EventLog –LogName ManageAD –Source “ManageUsers Script” –EntryType Information –EventID 1 –Message “User ” + $SAM + " has been disabled"

Write-EventLog : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Scriptâ??'.
At C:\test\ManageUsers.ps1:12 char:16
+     Write-EventLog <<<<  â?"LogName ManageAD â?"Source â?oManageUsers Scriptâ?? â?"EntryType Information â?"EventID
 â?"Message â?oUser â?? + $SAM + " has been disabled"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-EventLog], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you save scripts in UTF8 encoding, than use BOM. PowerShell does not detect UTF8, if file does not have BOM.

Comment: @PetSerAl So if the file was encoded with UTF8 and the BOM was present this would be ok? Is this true for other encoding or just UTF8?

Comment: @Matt For me PowerShell correctly handle that special quotes in dashes, as long as it can read them properly from file. I test only UTF8 and UTF16, both correctly detected from BOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want to say the simple answer is you have smart quotes in your code. Those came from where you originally copied that code or a product of your testing environment. Either way you need to watch out for those buggers.

```
Write-EventLog –LogName ManageAD –Source “ManageUsers Script” –EntryType Information –EventID 1 –Message “User ” + $SAM + " has been disabled"
```

Should be instead.

```
Write-EventLog –LogName ManageAD –Source "ManageUsers Script" –EntryType Information –EventID 1 –Message "User " + $SAM + " has been disabled"
```

I would like to point out from the error that I see other artifacts as well...

> **â?"**LogName ManageAD **â?"**

It makes me wonder if the hyphens are the long ones like an em-dash (Comes back to an earlier question about your editor choice!).

See the difference subtle here between the hyphen and 2 dashes - – —. Also have your dash against the basic hyphen. The one on the right is the hyphen.

[image]

Was the code working inside the ISE maybe and you were running the script in the regular console?